# ember.js build failing on Yosemite

Tags: ember.js

I don't think this is a problem with ember or npm. But I have no idea where to start looking either. I keep getting the following error message:

```
npm ERR! ember@1.8.0 build: `ember build --environment production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ember@1.8.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ember package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ember build --environment production
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ember
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/myname/Documents/Github/EmberJS
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

The contents of the npm-debug.log is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]

2 info using npm@1.4.28

3 info using node@v0.10.33

4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]

5 info prebuild ember@1.8.0

6 info build ember@1.8.0

7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 info ember@1.8.0 Failed to exec build script

9 error ember@1.8.0 build: `ember build --environment production`

9 error Exit status 1

10 error Failed at the ember@1.8.0 build script.

10 error This is most likely a problem with the ember package,

10 error not with npm itself.

10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

10 error     ember build --environment production

10 error You can get their info via:

10 error     npm owner ls ember

10 error There is likely additional logging output above.

11 error System Darwin 14.0.0

12 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"

13 error cwd /Users/dewald/Documents/Github/EmberJS

14 error node -v v0.10.33

15 error npm -v 1.4.28

16 error code ELIFECYCLE

17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Something else that I've noticed which may be related is the fact that the starter kit doesn't seem to work as it should. I tried both Safari (I'm on mac) and Google Chrome. Chrome does display the page but thats about it.

Thanks

Comment: The actual error causing this usually ends up in a npm-debug.log for one of your node_modules, as it is likely a compilation error with one of your supplementary modules.

Comment: Hi Fishbowl. Thank you for your response. I had a look there and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the documentation says:

1) npm install

2) npm run build

Thing is you also have to install some components via bower before you build. e.g.
bower install

Guess I have a newbie problem.